# Unable to calculate days difference from datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I tried to calculate days difference using jquery and bootstrap datepicker. I've tried numerous ways to calculate it, but it still didn't display anything. Is there something missing in my code? Could anyone please lend me a hand? I'm stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Date *</label>
  <div class="bfh-datepicker col-sm-3" data-format="d-m-y" data-date="today">
    <input id="mcDateFrom" type="text" name="mcDateFrom" >
  </div>
  <div class="bfh-datepicker col-sm-3" data-format="d-m-y" data-date="today">
    <input id="mcDateTo" type="text" name="mcDateTo">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="daysCount">
    <label id="daysCount"> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#mcDateFrom').datepicker({
        format: "d-m-y",
        todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
        autoclose: true,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
    }).on('change', function (ev) {
        $('#mcDateTo').datepicker('setStartDate', $("#mcDateFrom").val());
    });
    $('#mcDateTo').datepicker({
        format: "d-m-y",
        todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
        autoclose: true,
        minDate: '0',
        maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
    }).on('change', function (ev) {
        var start = $("#mcDateFrom").val();
        var startD = new Date(start);
        var end = $("#mcDateTo").val();
        var endD = new Date(end);
        var diff = parseInt((endD.getTime() - startD.getTime()) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
        $("#daysCount").append("<label> For " + diff + " Day(s) </label>");
});
```

Comment: You can use momentjs (https://momentjs.com ) library for datetime based calculation.

Answer (score 0):

There was several mistakes:

- bad date format, y shows as letter not year
- new Date() cant handle undefined custom format but Datepicker can return Date instance directly
- append in onChange event not works properly

Here is fixed and working version of your code:

```
$('#mcDateFrom').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('change', function(ev) {
    $('#mcDateTo').datepicker('setStartDate', $("#mcDateFrom").val());
});
$('#mcDateTo').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: '0',
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('change', function(ev) {
    var start = $("#mcDateFrom").data('datepicker').viewDate;
    var end = $("#mcDateTo").data('datepicker').viewDate;
    var diff = parseInt((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
    $("#daysCount").html("<label> For " + diff + " Day(s) </label>");
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m9x5jzmr/4/)

Comment: On JSFiddle it is working for you? Maybe you have different version of bootstrap datepicker

Comment: I see that mine is Bootstrap v3.0.3. Should I change to a different one?

Comment: What version did you use for your bootstrap datepicker? Because i see that when you choose the first date, the second automatically is set to days after the first date. Mine doesn't do that. I've retried your code on my project, but it won't work. Probably its because my version is not the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and now it's working well.
You need to change the format only and you will get the output as you required.

```js
$('#mcDateFrom').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('change', function(ev) {
   
    $('#mcDateTo').datepicker('setStartDate', $("#mcDateFrom").val());
});

$('#mcDateTo').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: '0',
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('change', function(ev) {

    var start = $("#mcDateFrom").data('datepicker').viewDate;
    var end = $("#mcDateTo").data('datepicker').viewDate;
    var diff = parseInt((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
  
    $("#daysCount").html("<label> For " + diff + " Day(s) </label>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Date *</label>
    <div class="bfh-datepicker col-sm-3" data-format="d-m-y" data-date="today">
        <input id="mcDateFrom" type="text" name="mcDateFrom">
    </div>
    <div class="bfh-datepicker col-sm-3" data-format="d-m-y" data-date="today">
        <input id="mcDateTo" type="text" name="mcDateTo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" id="daysCount">
        <label id="daysCount"> </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work as well. Nothing is displayed even after i added the scripts you provided :'(

Answer (score 0):

your are set wrong date format to "new Date" so it returns invalid date before diff.

```
var dateFrom;

$('#mcDateFrom').datepicker({
   format: "d-m-yy",
   todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
   autoclose: true,
   minDate: 0,
   maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('change', function (ev) {
   dateFrom = $("#mcDateFrom").val();
   $('#mcDateTo').datepicker('setStartDate', $("#mcDateFrom").val());
});

$('#mcDateTo').datepicker({
    format: "d-m-yy",
    todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
    minDate: '0',
    maxDate: '+1Y+6M'
}).on('change', function (ev) {
    startDP = dateFrom.split("-");
    var startD = new Date(startDP[2], (startDP[1]-1), startDP[0]);
    var end = $("#mcDateTo").val().split("-");
    var endD = new Date(end[2], (end[1]-1), end[0]);
    var diff = parseInt((endD.getTime() - startD.getTime()) / (24 * 3600 * 
1000));

   if( diff ) {
       $("#daysCount").append("<label> For " + diff + " Day(s) </label>");
   }
});
```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/wdjqh8c9/3/

Comment: On JsFiddle it is working fine.. did you add "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" script file after jquery... if so what is version of your "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" file.

Comment: Previously i didn't have any "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" file. Then i tried using the ones that dekts suggested, but still doesn't work. If its bootstrap.min.js, i'm using Bootstrap v3.0.3

Comment: please add files with this sequence:


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

and please check console and let me know is there any error.

Comment: and check this example, in this example i also use Bootstrap v3.0.3.

https://jsfiddle.net/wdjqh8c9/5/